# How to escape angular2 field validation pattern

Tags: validation, angular

How to place pattern regex in angular2 form
I have this pattern

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-form',
    template: `
        <h2>My Form</h2>
        <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(ff)" #ff="ngForm">
            <div>
                <label for="mail">Field</label>
                <input ngControl="Field" type="text" id="email" required #email="ngForm" pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*$">
                <span class="error" *ngIf="!email.valid">Not valid</span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" [disabled]="!ff.valid">Submit</button>
        </form>
    `
})
```

I am getting an errors in my pattern regex. Is there a way to escape it somehow?

That is some of errors I am getting on that regex:

```
[tslint] expected an assignment or function call
[tslint] missing whitespace
[ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
[ts] Cannot find name 'a'.
[tslint] expected an assignment or function call
[tslint] missing whitespace
[ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
[ts] The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.
[ts] Cannot find name 'a'.
[tslint] missing whitespace
[ts] Expression expected.
```

[image]

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer just updated

Comment: Have you tried to move the HTML to use to its own file and use `templateUrl` instead of `template`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `\` before  ` (backtick)

```
pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_\`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*$"
```

or move the template to an HTML file and use `templateUrl` instead of `template`

Comment: Which way? . . . .

Comment: looks like something wrong with the pattern thing. I just put this regex `pattern="^\S+@\S+$"` for test and it is not working either. The field is always invalid

Comment: Have you tried moving the HTML out of the `*.ts` file?

Comment: Do you see the `patter` attribute in the browser? Is it the same as in your source file?

Comment: Yeas I checked if `pattern` is in the browser and it was. However moving the template to html file did the trick. But why it is wasn't working inline?

Comment: With the unescaped backtick in the pattern it's obvious. You use the backtick to create a multiline string and using the same quote inside the string unescaped can't work. I don't know why it doesn't work when you add `\`. It seems to pass the pattern to the HTML correctly. Can you make it reproduce in this Plunker? https://plnkr.co/edit/2gWrIQ?p=preview ?

Comment: the planker is exactly working for me could be issues in my code